# Transpose rows to columns every time a criteria is met

Tags: excel, vba

I converted a csv from a project manager interface into Excel to report on tasks my department has done this year.

A snapshot of a portion of my workbook:
[image: Uncleaned workbook]

Every project has a unique card id that starts with a 6 in the A column of this workbook. This is the only thing that starts with a 6 in this column so this would be the ideal criteria to transpose off of. The amount of rows between each project is variable.

I would like the macro to create a worksheet in which each project has its own row. I would like the data in the rows between each project to be transposed into columns that coincide with the project they belong to.

I would like the final product to look something like this:
[image: ideal solution]

I tried creating VBA code that would transpose the rows to columns every x rows. This does not work as there is a different amount of rows between each unique project.

Excel available for download [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NubA6V40Zd_t6I1yvy8TtdiC22AbYtIE/view?usp=sharing)

CSV available for download [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cHat8u_D_7-YAB7W9hPbGE1sT4B4L-jm/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Would probably be more useful to post a screenshot of the source file opened in (eg) Notepad - looks like when opened as CSV in Excel it doesn't quite manage to display correctly.

Comment: ...also if you could share a sample file (redacted as/if needed)

Comment: Just edited the original post to include a downloadable copy of the excel file

Comment: More useful to provide the source CSV - after opening in Excel it's more difficult to parse....

Comment: Just edited the original post to include a downloadable copy of the csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Const HDR As String = "Card Description"
    Dim col As Collection, ln, rw As Range, v, c As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim m, arr, colNum, nextPos As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    m = Application.Match(HDR, ws.Rows(1), 0)   'find the column header
    If IsError(m) Then
        MsgBox "column header '" & HDR & "' not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    nextPos = m + 1 'first position for any added column
    'loop over all "Description" cells
    For Each c In ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, m), ws.Cells(Rows.Count, m).End(xlUp)).Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(c) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print "parsing", c.Address
            arr = Split(v, vbLf)  'split into lines
            colNum = 0            'reset destination column
            For Each ln In arr    'loop over lines
                ln = Trim(ln)
                'is this line a tag?
                If Len(ln) > 4 And Left(ln, 2) = "**" And Right(ln, 2) = "**" Then
                    colNum = Application.Match(ln, ws.Rows(1), 0) 'already added?
                    If IsError(colNum) Then
                        ws.Columns(nextPos).Insert                'add a column
                        ws.Cells(1, nextPos).Value = ln           'add the header
                        colNum = nextPos                          'set the current output column
                        nextPos = nextPos + 1                     'for the next one...
                    End If
                Else
                    If colNum > 0 Then                            'in a tagged section?
                        With c.EntireRow.Cells(colNum)
                            .Value = .Value & ln                  'append in relevant column
                        End With
                    End If
                End If
            Next ln
        End If
    Next c
    
End Sub
```

Source File:
[image]

After running the macro:
[image]

Comment: This Macro isn't doing anything to my sheet. Other Macros I run work (like a blank row deleter) but this one left me with an unedited sheet.

Comment: The screenshot you posted doesn't look correct - I will add a screenshot of how it looks for me after opening the CSV